# DFRobot_RGB1602 library does not work properly with DFRobot DFR0554 and Raspberry Pi Pico

Tags: python, i2c, lcd, pi-pico, micropython

Problem summary: set_cursor(0,0) brings text to (2,1) and set_cursor(0,1) brings text to (3,1), texts goes to imaginary 3rd line before 2nd line as if a 20x4 display.

I modified the Python code to work with the Raspberry Pi Pico.

- replaced "import sys,wiringpi" with "from machine import Pin,I2C"
- replaced wiringpi.wiringPiI2CWriteReg8() with I2C.writeto_mem()
- added set_cursor_custom method for troubleshooting (to no avail)
- replaced wiringpi.wiringPiI2CSetup() with I2C
- added sda, scl and i2cn keywords to **init** for custom pin numbers

When I run it using the following script (full included in zip):

```
import RGB1602
import time
from machine import Pin, I2C

lcd=RGB1602.RGB1602(16,2, sda=Pin(14), scl=Pin(15), i2cn=1)
  
#set the cursor to column 0, line 1
lcd.set_cursor(0, 0)
lcd.print_out("abcdefgh")
lcd.set_cursor(0, 1)
lcd.print_out("ABCDEFG")
```

The following text is printed onto the screen: (dashes represent space and are for easy counting)

```
--              |
--aABCDEFG      |
```

Which is not the expected behaviour. The expected behaviour is:

```
abcdefgh        |
ABCDEFG         |
```

Another grievance is that text doesn't go to the next line properly. When I run the following script (also in zip):

```
import RGB1602
import time
from machine import Pin, I2C

lcd=RGB1602.RGB1602(16,2, sda=Pin(14), scl=Pin(15), i2cn=1)

lcd.print_out("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
```

It prints:

```
stuvwxyzijklmnop|
OPQRSTUVWXYZ1234|
```

Instead of the expected:

```
abcdefghijklmnop|
qrstuvwxyzABCDEF|
```

Please fix this. Thank you.

Below is the zip of test files (modified lib and test script)
[test&lib.zip](https://github.com/DFRobot/DFRobot_RGBLCD1602/files/7786825/test.lib.zip)

(adapted from GitHub issue)

Edit: I guess the question is: How can I properly edit the library file such that the expected behaviour occurs?

Comment: please do not crosspost ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70547553/dfrobot-rgb1602-library-does-not-work-properly-with-dfrobot-dfr0554-and-raspberr ... wait for answers in the first post .... it helps if you actually ask a question

Comment: @jsotola no one has answered there yet